# Bash counting on variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable called `ip` that contains a list of IPs.

```
$ echo $ip
218.25.208.92 218.25.208.92 53.170.26.175 
8.135.72.164 244.105.203.71 211.118.89.4 
100.29.91.148 187.225.13.147 48.204.157.1452 182.237.138.26 182.237.138.26 182.237.138.26
211.118.89.4 100.29.91.148 100.29.91.148
```

I am trying to iterate over this string and find the IPs which are repeated more than 2 times. If the IP is repeated more than two times, show the amount of times the IP is found.

I thought this could be managed with a for loop, but I am quite lost.

I tried using `grep -o`. It shows how many times that IP appears, but I have to specify each IP manually...

```
echo $ip | grep -o 218.25.208.92 | wc -l
```

Newer code:

```
for i in $ip; do
    echo $ip | grep -o $i | wc -l
done
```

Comment: Use the `uniq` command with the `-c` and `-d` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
ip='218.25.208.92 218.25.208.92 53.170.26.175
8.135.72.164 244.105.203.71 211.118.89.4
100.29.91.148 187.225.13.147 48.204.157.1452 182.237.138.26
182.237.138.26 182.237.138.26
211.118.89.4 100.29.91.148 100.29.91.148'
```

The critical part you are missing is how bash handles separating words. Bash provides an *Internal Field Separator* which defaults to `IFS=$' \t\n'` (`space`, `tab`, `newline`). When you need to access individual words, you simply need to allow default word-splitting to occur.

Quoting prevents word splitting. So to allow default word splitting to take place, you must use `$ip` unquoted. There is no need to spawn separate subshell calling additional Linux utilities, bash provides all you need as built-ins.

To simply iterate over each separate IP, you can just loop over the contents of `$ip` treating it as a list, e.g.

```
for i in $ip; do
    # make use of $i any way you like
    echo $i
done
```

You can simply create an array from the contents of `$ip` by declaring an array and initializing it with `$ip`, e.g.

```
array=( $ip )
```

If you just want to separate each IP on its own line, you can use the *printf trick*, e.g.

```
printf "%s\n" $ip
```

Where the `printf` format string, despite having a single string conversion specifier, will exhaust all input outputting each IP on a separate line.

Comment: Be aware that not quoting `$ip` means it's subject to glob expansion. If it contains `*`, `?`, or other wildcard characters they could be expanded. It's safe with a variable that only contains IP addresses, but I would not recommend this for variables containing arbitrary text or user input.

Comment: Yes, that is a good addition. There are limitations to what contents you can safely use unquoted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To count, in my case, how many times an IP appears on a string is made with
the following command:

```
(IFS=""; sort <<< "$ip") | uniq -c
```

Comment: Better `printf "%s\n" $ip | uniq -c` -- no need to change the default `IFS`. Good luck with your scripting!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `IFS` is changed in a subshell so there's no lasting harm. An unquoted `$ip`, on the other hand, is subject to word splitting (good) but also glob expansion (bad).

Comment: @JohnKugelman -- yep, I caught that, the intent was to explain no subshell was necessary -- I guess that is how I should have phased it instead of just `"Better"`.

Comment: turn off globbing with `set -f`

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this, use `uniq`, but bash only:

```sh
IFS=$' \n' read -r -a ips -d '' <<<"$ip"
declare -A count
for i in "${ips[@]}"; do
    (( count["$i"]++ ))
done
for i in "${!count[@]}"; do
    (( count["$i"] > 2 )) && printf "%s\t%d\n" "$i" "${count[$i]}"
done
```

```
100.29.91.148   3
182.237.138.26  3
```

The one advantage to this approach is that the variables are always quoted  so there will be no surprises with filename expansion.